# How can i access different models with same plural in loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I want to access different models with same plurals. Is there any way in loopback to do so, e.g.:

get-account.json

```
{
    "name": "getAccount",
    "plural": "account"
}
```

to access get-account.js and inside it remoteMethod with http path `/`

get-smtp-account.json

```
{
    "name": "getSmtpAccount",
    "plural": "account"
}
```

to access get-smtp-account.js and inside it remoteMethod with http path `/smtp`

Comment: url will be like `http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/account/` and `http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/account/smtp/`

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I am just exploring loopback..What can be done and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the point of Restful resources.

The restful specification is all about using the http verbs, representing CRUD actions like this:

> GET: READ -
>   POST: CREATE -
>   PUT: UPDATE -
>   DELETE: DELETE

Each model should represent a resource, that would be the name of a single entry in the persistance, for example, **account**.

Because we are storing a collection of models, we use a "plural" to refer to this resources, thats why all endpoints should be named in plural, in this example that would be **accounts**.

So, in any restful resource, if you wanna read data from the persistance, you should use

GET http://0.0.0.0/api/accounts

In loopback, you can create relations between models. This relations, are representations of the relations in the persistance (db). So you can create a model called "**smtp**".

After the relation is made, you can query the account and "include" the smtp relation, bringing together all users with their data.

Check the documentation for more information https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+model+relations

If you have more questions, like, how to create relations between models, i'm really happy to help you in another question.

Comment: I have found something in the loopback called `http` in .json of every model. You can specifiy path inside like <code>{
  "name": "getAccount",
  "plural": "account",
  "http": {
    "path": "/account/info/"
  }}</code> and for other <code>{
  "name": "getSmtpAccount",
  "plural":"account",
  "http":{
    "path":"/account/smtp/"
  }}</code>.. both are valid and representing an end point

Comment: the only thing that left for me is I want access to `getAccount` with `/account` only.

Comment: FYI, these paths are generated from swagger.

Comment: I know, but the models name is getAccount and getAccountSmtp and should be account and smtp